# Last record in table repeating when I try to display it in MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC web application and I am running into an issue when I try to display the populated model into a table.  I should display 30 unique records but the last record is showing 30 times.  When I use a break line and step through, it appears to be populating with the unique records.  Below is my controller and view.

Model:

```
namespace WebServicesApp.Models
{
    public class FilingViewModel
   {
   public static Filing filing = new Filing();
   public static FilingMaster filingMaster = new FilingMaster();
   }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult FilingHomePage()
    {

        DatabaseClass db = new DatabaseClass();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        var model = new List<FilingViewModel>();

        db.GetFiling(ref ds, "10600");

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            var filingViewModel = new FilingViewModel();
            FilingViewModel.filing.Service = dr.Field<string>("Service");
            FilingViewModel.filing.filing_Description = dr.Field<string>("filing_Description");
            FilingViewModel.filing.Date_Post = dr.Field<DateTime>``("Date_Due");
            model.Add(filingViewModel);
        }


        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
@using WebServicesApp.Models
@model List<FilingViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "FilingHomePage";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Welcome to Filing Center</h2>
    <p>From here you can see your returns that need to be filed, view your 
       filing history, and create a new filing record</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Returns to File</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>The following are returns that need to be filed. Please select </p>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Filing Name</th>
                            <th>Filing Description</th>
                            <th>Date Posted</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>


                        @foreach (var filing in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@FilingViewModel.filing.Service
                                <td>@FilingViewModel.filing.filing_Description</td>
                                <td>@FilingViewModel.filing.Date_Post</td>
                                <td><a>Select</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Return History</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Below is a list of filings that have been posted</p>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Filing Name</th>
                        <th>Filing Description</th>
                        <th>Date Posted</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 @*<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Create New Filing</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Here you can enter information for a filing that does not exist yet.</p>
            <form class="form-horizontal">

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>*@
</div>
```

Comment: How are you setting the properties of your `filingViewModel` ? I see you are creating a new instance and adding it to the `model` list, but the properties are not being set in your instances. I'm your view you seems to be accessing a static instance (`FilingViewModel`) instead of accessing the `filling` variable.

Comment: Replace @@FilingViewModel.filing.xxx with @@filing.xxx

Comment: I have two models that I am going to use for this view(Filing, and FilingMaster).  I created the FilingViewModel model in order to do this.  I edited the question to include the model.

Comment: You have `static` fields!- they need to be properties - `public Filing filing { get; set; }` and `public FilingMaster filingMaster { get; set }`

Comment: You need to change your model, you are using static field, so this will be the same value for all instance of this. Change the Static for a properties on public class FilingViewModel and instanciate on the constructor of this. Then in the foreach row, you need to change to use the instance ( now are using the class ). All the rest looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your model:

```
namespace WebServicesApp.Models
{
    public class FilingViewModel
   {
     public FilingViewModel() {
       this.filing = new Filing();
       this.filingMaster = new FilingMaster();
     }

     public Filing filing {get;set;}
     public FilingMaster filingMaster  {get;set;}
   }
}
```

Then in your Controller

```
    var model = new FilingViewModel();
   foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            var filingViewModel = new FilingViewModel();
            filingViewModel .filing.Service = dr.Field<string>("Service");
            filingViewModel .filing.filing_Description = dr.Field<string>("filing_Description");
            filingViewModel .filing.Date_Post = dr.Field<DateTime>``("Date_Due");
            model.Add(filingViewModel);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked.  Could you please give an explanation as to why?

Comment: You used Static Field, this save one value for all instance of this Class. Is a OOP Concept. ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static ). So in your code, these have the last value set ( last row ), and all instance show the same value.

Answer (score 0):

In your model

```
public class FilingViewModel
{
   public List<Filing> Filings { get; set; };
}
```

In your controller

```
var model = new FilingViewModel();
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        var filing = new Filing();
        filing.Service = dr.Field<string>("Service");
        filing.filing_Description = dr.Field<string>("filing_Description");
        filing.Date_Post = dr.Field<DateTime>``("Date_Due");
        model.Filings.Add(filing);
    }
```

In your view:

```
@model FilingViewModel

@foreach (var filing in Model.Filings)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@filing.Service
                                <td>@filing.filing_Description</td>
                                <td>@filing.Date_Post</td>
                                <td><a>Select</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        }
```

Comment: When I do this I get a red line under filingViewModel.filing that states "Member cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead."

Comment: It is because you marked filing as static. If you don't need to access that property outside of your viewmodel then you should remove that. Should look like:  public Filing filing  { get; set; }

Comment: the reason you are getting the last one every time is because you are newing up the Filing object in your ViewModel and then, in your controller loop, you are assigning values to *that* Filing object instead of creating a new one every time. And then in your view you are again accessing *that* Filing object instead of looping through multiple like should be happening.

Comment: The best solution here would probably be to change your ViewModel to have a list of Filing objects on it. Then in your controller, loop through the data and new up a Filing object, assign its values, then stick it in that list. Then, pass that viewmodel with the list of Filings into the view and loop through that instead. So the loop in your view it would be something like @foreach(var filing in Model.Filings) then the td's would look like <td>@filing.Date_Post</td>

Comment: edited my code snippets to reflect my recommendation in previous comment

Answer (score 0):

I think the razor part should be;

```
@foreach (var filing in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@filing.filing.Service
        <td>@filing.filing.filing_Description</td>
        <td>@filing.filing.Date_Post</td>
        <td><a>Select</a></td>
    </tr>
}
```